# Django: Pass argument through response redirect

Tags: python, django

```
urlpatterns = patterns('tourney.views',
    url(r'^(?P<tourney_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'tourney', name="tourney"),
)

#views.py:
def tourney(request,
            tourney_slug,
            message = None,
            template_name="tourney/tourney.html"
            ):
    tourney = Tourney.objects.get(slug=tourney_slug)
    message = message
    print(message)


#/somewhereElse
message = "Please enter valid values for submission."
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tourney:tourney', 
                                    args=(tourney_slug,)
                                   ),
                            message=message
                            )
```

A page called somewhereElse redirects the user to the `tourney` view.  This code successfully redirects to the tourney view, but for some reason message isn't passed along as an argument.  What is wrong with my construction of the `HttpResponseRedirect`?

Comment: how about setting message inside `args` ?

Comment: No, then the lookup fails, I'm guessing because message isn't an argument which applies to the url, it is just an argument passed through to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirect just means that your browser will load the url specified in the redirect instead of the current page. It is processed in Django as a separate request, so it doesn't share state and the message argument gets lost. The `HttpResponseRedirect` also doesn't have a `message` argument to begin with, so passing it to the response isn't going to work.

What you probably want is to store the message in a cookie or session, and retrieve and display it on the next request. One way to do this is with the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).

Comment: Messages indeed, that was just the ticket.  Thanks for the explanation!  Got it working now with messages.